# react/redux/immutable/redux persist: not persisting to localstorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js, redux-persist

Searched, and only found questions loosely related to my question.

Have a redux application where the state is composed of Immutable Records.

Looking to serialize / deserialize only a subset of my state to localstorage:

```
\Application <- Immutable Record
    \user <- regular js object
    \...
\...
```

This is my current `configureStore`:

```
import {
  compose, createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers,
} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { routerMiddleware, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import immutableTransform from 'redux-persist-transform-immutable';
import { Application } from '../modules/application/records/application';
import rootReducer from '../modules/reducers';

const persistConfig = {
  transforms: [immutableTransform()],
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const history = createHistory();
const reduxRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);

const reducer = combineReducers({
  ...rootReducer,
  routing: routerReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, reduxRouterMiddleware, createLogger()),

  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f,
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(persistedReducer, initialState);

  // reduxRouterMiddleware.listenForReplays(store);

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../modules/reducers', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../modules/reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  return persistStore(store);
}
```

Right now, this not only isn't persisting any data to my localstorage, it's somehow forcing all of my state to be `null`, so that, for instance, `Application` has no children, where I expect a `user`.

How do I correctly configure my `configureStore` to persist only the `Application/user` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update my `configureStore` as follows:

```
import {
  compose, createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers,
} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { routerMiddleware, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import immutableTransform from 'redux-persist-transform-immutable';
import { Application } from '../modules/application/records/application';
import rootReducer from '../modules/reducers';

const persistConfig = {
  transforms: [immutableTransform()],
  key: 'root',
  whitelist: 'application',
  storage,
};

const history = createHistory();
const reduxRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);

const reducer = combineReducers({
  ...rootReducer,
  routing: routerReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);

const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, reduxRouterMiddleware, createLogger()),

  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension({ trace: true }) : f => f,
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(persistedReducer, initialState);

  // reduxRouterMiddleware.listenForReplays(store);

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../modules/reducers', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../modules/reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }
  const persister = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persister };
}
```

Because I am in a React project, I also needed to update my routing to use a `PersistGate` element:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

import configureStore from './client/store/configureStore';

const { store, persister } = configureStore();
const { dispatch } = store;

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persister}>
      <BrowserRouter>
         {Routes here...}
      </BrowserRouter>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

dispatch(actions.initializeApp());
```